# Do I need to explicitly trim a CHAR-column?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query checks, if any of the listed values are present in a table:

```sql
SELECT c FROM t WHERE RTRIM(c) IN ('string1', 'string2', ... 'stringN')
```

The type of the column `c` is `CHAR`, which would seem to require the use of `RTRIM()` to get rid of the padding, when comparing the values with the enumerated ones.

However, I tried running the query without the `RTRIM()` and it returned the exact same results -- even though all of the values in `c` are shorter than the maximum width.

Moreover, if I pad the enumerated strings with spaces on the right, the results are *still* the same. That is, `'MEOW      '` is in `('MEOW')` as well as in `('MEOW  ')`.

This seems odd -- is this how things are supposed to work, or we should not rely on it? We're still on Oracle-11 now, is this standard behavior, or might it change in the future?

It matters to us to not only because of the æstethics, but also because we'd like to add an index on the column -- and would rather avoid the use of "functional index" (`RTRIM()` being the function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for comparison `char()` columns usually specify that the values are padded out to the length of the longer one.

Hence, spaces at the end of the comparison strings are optional.

This is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51038):

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. . . . If two values have no differing characters, then they are considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of data type CHAR, NCHAR, . . .

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply. So `RTRIM()` is, indeed, unnecessary -- and the index can be based simply on the value of the `t` itself, right?

Comment: @MikhailT. . . . It is unnecessary.  However, I would recommend storing that value as `varchar2()`.

Comment: Yes, I would too. But this table is maintained by a vendor-provided software, so it is not up to us :(